# Firebase asynchronous answer DispatchGroup

Tags: firebase, swift3

Hi I'm trying to create a variable to go through my database [Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SqJq.png) 
each event(in the database EVENT regroups clubs which have events)
must have the function mapviewEdit applied to its content.

```
    ref.child("Events").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children
            {
                let snapitty = child as! DataSnapshot
                myGroupBackTo.notify(queue: .main)
                {
                    print(incrementClub)
                    incrementClub += 1
                    multiple = false
                    print("BACK TO FALSE")
                }
            myGroupBackTo.enter()

            if let result = snapitty.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]
            {

                    for child in result
                    {

                        mapviewEdit(incrementClub: incrementClub)

                    }

            myGroupBackTo.leave()}
            }
        })
        { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Here is the beginning of mapviewEdit :

```
        func mapviewEdit(incrementClub: Int){

            self.ref.child("Events").child("\(incrementClub)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snap in
```

My problem being that incrementClub does seem to increment to the next club, it always returns the first event of the first club, here is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YnoZ.png) (it is normal that it prints x times the same event but not always the first of the first club)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You are using dispatchgroups in a not-async function...

Comment: ok so why does it not take in account the incrementation?
it does 1,2,3,4...315 and then does the function